# What is the difference between these two interface declarations?

Tags: typescript, function, interface, arrow-functions

What is the difference between these two interface declarations :

```js
interface A {
  foo: (x: number) => number;
}

const a: A = {
  foo: (x: number) => (x + 1);
}
```

```js
interface B {
  foo(x: number): number;
}

const b: B = {
  foo(x: number) {
    return x + 1;
  }
}
```

My guess is that `foo` in `A` is declared as an arrow function while `foo` in `B` is `Function` object (with its own `this` etc.), but I'm not sure. I couldn't find any info on this online, even after searching through the TypeScript doc. By the way, if you find anything online about this, I would be interested in knowing how did you find it (what did you type on Google to get your answer :p )

Comment: They are interchangeable in your example

Comment: They are mostly the same, but when [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) is enabled, then the function-valued property is checked more strictly than the method is; see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N55adN)

Comment: See the linked questions and answers for more information.  To find these other questions I searched for "function property" and "method" and "TypeScript" and "difference".